# Regarding Paschen curves for Venusian air composition

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, voltage, plasma-physics

I'm curious what the breakdown voltages look like for the venusian atmosphere, specifically at the surface of venus. How much power and voltage  would be required to start an arc, and how much power and voltage would be required to sustain an arc? Also, regarding an open arc, would there be a way to confine an arc to a line rather than having the arc rise due to the plasma heating? Would it be more energy efficient to start a plasma with some other form of radiation?

Comment: 90 atmospheres of CO2? That is going to be really hard to get breakdown (easier than in SF6, but still). See https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/11/4/902 and extrapolate out quite a ways.

Comment: Using Jon's linked reference, a very cursory hand-wavy extrapolation I find something north of 300 kV for a breakdown voltage in $CO_{2}$ at ~90 bars.  It's not outlandishly large, but it's also not likely to be something commonly occurring (unless volcanic ash gets to higher potentials than typical thunderstorms?).